# Making a simple templating engine in PHP

Tags: php, regex, templating, preg-replace-callback, templating-engine

I need to write a simple PHP function to replace text between `{{ }}` characters with their respective data.

**Example:**

String: "*and with strange aeons even* `{{noun}}` *may* `{{verb}}`"

`$data = ['noun' => 'bird', 'verb' => 'fly'];`

Result:

"*and with strange aeons even **bird** may **fly***"

I have it almost working with the following code based on `preg_replace_callback`

```
function compile($str,$data){

    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        $pattern = '/\b(?<!\-)(' . $k . ')\b(?!-)/i';
        $str = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) use($v){
            return $v;
        }, $str);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

But I cant seem to account for the `{{ }}`.

The result looks like this:

"*and with strange aeons even **{{bird}}** may **{{fly}}***"

How can I adjust the regex and/or code to account for the double curly brackets?

Also, before anyone asks why I'm trying to do this manually rather than use PHP itself or the [Smarty](https://www.smarty.net/) plugin -- its too narrow a use case to install a plugin and I cannot use PHP itself because the input string is coming in as raw text from a database. I need to compile that raw text with data stored in a PHP array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're looping anyway, keep it simple:

```
foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
    $str = str_ireplace('{{'.$k.'}}', $v, $str);
}
```

You can add a space before `{{` and after `}}` if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```php
$str = "and with strange aeons even {{noun}} may {{verb}}";
$data = ['noun' => 'bird', 'verb' => 'fly'];

$pattern = '/{{(' . implode('|', array_keys($data)) . ')}}/i';
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) use($data){
    return $data[strtolower($m[1])];
}, $str);
// => and with strange aeons even bird may fly
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/nrQ4t).

The `$pattern` will look like `/{{(noun|verb)}}/i`, and will match `noun` or `verb` inside double braces while capturing the word itself. The replacement will be the corresponding key value of the `$data` array. Turning the Group 1 value to lower case with `strtolower($m[1])` is required since the keys in the `$data` array are all lowercase, and the `$pattern` can match uppercase variants, too.

Comment: clever solution. and best of all, it worked! Thank you

Comment: I would suggest applying `preg_quote()` to `array_keys($data)` using `array_map()` in the event that a key contains a special character.

Comment: Something similar might need to be done to the values given to `preg_replace_callback()` in the event that a value contains `$1` or something.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus If that is necessary, I will add `implode("|", array_map(function($i) { return preg_quote(trim($i), "/"); }, array_keys($data)))` to the answer instead of `implode('|', array_keys($data))`. I doubt `noun`, `verb`, any POS value has got more than a letter.

Comment: I really can't predict OP's future plans but it's better to harden the code ahead of time rather than trying to debug a future issue especially if OP is not the one maintaining the code in the future.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus There is nothing to harden in this case. POS values are composed solely of letters.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [`strtr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) and call it a day:

```
$string = 'and with strange aeons even {{noun}} may {{verb}}';

$data = ['{{noun}}' => 'bird', '{{verb}}' => 'fly'];

echo strtr( $string, $data );
```

produces:

```
and with strange aeons even bird may fly
```

`strtr()` is nice because it won't mess up the string in the event of:

```
$data = ['{{noun}}' => 'bi{{verb}}rd', '{{verb}}' => 'fly'];
```

Comment: `strstr` is a good solution if you can control the array keys and add the `'{{ }}` to them.